# Using a Hidden Twitter Account

Tags: twitter, ios5

Not sure if any one has tried this. I want to access twitter with an account that the user of the phone doesn't have access to.

The way I have looked at it is by adding a twitter account using the OAth (token/secret)

I can add an account using the following code.

```
NSString *token = @"blahblahblah";
NSString *secret = @"blahblahblah";

ACAccountStore *store = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountCredential *credential = [[ACAccountCredential alloc] initWithOAuthToken:token tokenSecret:secret];

ACAccountType *twitterAcctType = [store accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

ACAccount *newAccount = [[ACAccount alloc] initWithAccountType:twitterAcctType];
newAccount.credential = credential;

[store saveAccount:<#(ACAccount *)#> withCompletionHandler:<#^(BOOL success, NSError *error)completionHandler#>    

[store saveAccount:newAccount withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@"Account was saved!");
    } else {
        //something went wrong, check value of error
    }
}];
```

But this code stores the user id associataed with the secret in the iphones account store. The problem being that if the phone user then uses twitter the account privilages are still there for him to use...

There doesn't seem to be a `store deleteAccount` method implemented

For my second attempt i tried using just the user that was created without adding it to the account store but I think the SaveAccount method is what verifies the token and secret and gets the user name...

Any tips???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a friendly reminder that this will most likely have your app banned from the app store, as this can easily be classified as spying on the user/device, *if* you can pull it off which I doubt.

Also, beware of having thousands/millions of users twitting from the same account.

Finally, there does not seem to be a way to remove the account, as you said, plus in order to use it you'd need to use requestAccessToAccountsWithType:withCompletionHandler: which would trigger a notice to the user and would make them think you were requesting access to *his* tweeter account, rather than yours...

Comment: Thanks for this Fenando, and I understood all the constraints. We actually abandoned this way of trying to do it in the end. But thanks for the comments.